# Is this spyware on my site or a real Java update?

Tags: php, html

I run a small WordPress website for the wife

http://craftybluefox.com

I keep getting this java update box poping up only on her site and looking at the links they go to somesite ppv2014.info which can't be real

Now my question how can I track this down and remove it? I've had a good look in the files for her site but can't seem to find it.

In case you do not see the pop up this is what I see.

[image]

Comment: How did you make the website? Did you write it yourself or use some dodgy wordpress or joomla nonsense?

Comment: This seems very fake to me - it's cleary a JS pop up of some sort (typically called an overlay). I can't imagine Java doing it this way. You could always hit F12 and see what is going on in the DOM. I would suspect though the detail is being loaded form your site but everything else is hosted else where... I also now guess you used some web site builder, which are IMO terribly insecure, easy to hack, and potentially dangerious

Comment: There is no legitimate functionality in Java that would generate this window.  Its malicious and your website is sending anyone that visits it infections.  Nuke from orbit and restore the website from offline backups.  This can't be a legitimate question, because you know the website its sending to you, isn't an Oracle website.

Comment: @dave It's wordpress yes and no ive not used any website building programs

Comment: But you are using third party plugins? If so (and I'm not being rude), what do you (anyone) expect? I'm a developer (web/software) and would never touch it for this reason. Lots of the time, the advice is to update passwords/log in details etc but, in this case, you need to find a back up , completely remove the site, purge where it lived with fire, utter some voodoo spell, curse wordpress, realise the errors of using word press, and start again :)

Comment: Well im no web developer so plugins are a must for us. Never had a problem before but I do know what you mean. Just trying to track down there this is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an iframe injection according to the source code:

`<iframe src="http://ppv2014.info/Java-Recommended%20Update.htm" style="min-width:100%; min-height:100%; height:100%; width:100%; max-width:100%; max-height:100%; overflow: auto; border:none;" frameborder="no"></iframe>`

It seems to be enclosed in a div called "pop":

`<div class="pop" id="pop" style="position: fixed; z-index: 100002; border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); height: 60%; width: 60%; top: 20%; left: 20%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">...</div>`

My best guess is that you have an extension that has been compromised. Disable extensions one by  one until it disappears. Failing that, change the theme to see if it's an infected theme. And failing that, back up the Wordpress database and reinstall it.

Comment: Can't seem to find it using Grep also all plugins are off and im still getting it.

Comment: The theme may be compromised. Did changing that have any effect? Common exploits like this hide their code (usually by encoding it) so finding it is difficult.

Comment: Was in the theme. Very odd and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have iframe on your page. Of course, it's malware. Try to find any iframe or ppv2014 string in content of files on your page, also check javascript files if they are not changed, by time changed or some other way.
If you are using some CMS, it will be good to update it for a newest version. Also some CMS or own coded systems have their own logging in some files or in DB, so it would be good starting point to check them.

Malicious robots are browsing whole internet and they are trying to find some specific files to raise some vulnerability, server or CMS systems. These attempts should be logged (especially every answer with other result than 200) in some files. Try to find at least logs from  your webpage, if you don't have access to webserver.

Comment: Not all iframes are malware dolmayan. I'll recheck the javascript again.